# HTML5 pushState bugging at refresh

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following piece of code in my webpage:

```
$("#expertise").click(function(){ 
   $("#content").load('expertise.php'); 
   window.history.pushState('','Expertise','expertise.php'); 
});
```

(I have similar code for other jQuery selectors.)

When I refresh the page, it just loads the "expertise.php" page and other parts of the webpage are lost. Any idea how to solve this? 

I saw that "history.js" solves this problem but I want to fix this code itself.

Comment: It just pushes something to the adress bar, it does'nt apply magic to page refresh, i.e. hitting F5 etc.

Comment: Got it. I think my approach is wrong. Can you tell me how do I make this browser-friendly by allowing the user to refresh?

Comment: You have an actual page at that adress that shows what you load when using HTML5 History.

Comment: I get it. I am attempting to create a single page app. Is 'history.js' the best solution for this currently?

Comment: As far as I know that's the best plugin, but I think it's no longer developed or updated, and has'nt been in some time. It's not that hard to do without a plugin either, but it requires some reading.